# Embedded C: Risk of Initializing global data

Tags: c, embedded

General question in c langage:

Is it safe to initialize data in the declaration?
example:

```
static unsigned char myVar =5u;
```

Is there any risk that this value will be overwritten by the startup code?

Comment: It's safe, but your other question can't be answered without taking a look at that "startup code". I mean, it's perfectly legitimate for the main or some other method to overwrite this value.

Comment: In fact I'm evaluating two methods: initialization as I described in the post and initialization using init function. which is the safest way?

Comment: what do you mean, they're both safe, but nothing prevents you (or your collegue) from initializing the value to `5u` in the declaration, and then overwriting it with `13u` in the `main()`. Only human hands and bad ideas will be a source of bugs in initializing variables.

Comment: Why do you think it could not be safe? You could as well ask if it is safe to assume that `a` contains 4 after `a = 2 + 2;`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've heard of cases where global variables can be overwritten before `main` starts, I believe in embedded systems where there is some linker trickery going on.  I'd have to dig around to find confirmation of that.

Comment: Note that it is not a global if you declare it static. It has scope limited to the translation unit in which it is declared.

Comment: @dbush The linker does not generate code. The start-up code is what performs the initialisation. We cannot answer the question in the basis of yes you can write your own startup code and get it wrong, or apply non standard behaviour.. We have to assume a valid C runtime that conforms to standard. If the user has applied alternative startup behaviour, that is for them to know and understand the consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, embedded systems microcontroller projects come in two flavours and the IDE often lets you pick one:

- Standard C compliant (sometimes referred to as "ANSI" by confused tool vendors).
- Minimized start-up.

The former, standard C compliant projects *require* that all variables with static storage duration, such as those declared at file scope and/or with the keyword `static` are initialized before main() is called. This initialization happens inside the start-up code ("C run-time"/"CRT"). On such a system, the `myVar = 5u;` is guaranteed to be written (not overwritten) by the start-up code. It copies down the value 5 from flash to RAM.

The latter, "mimizined"/"fast" start-up version is not strictly C standard compliant. In such projects all the initialization code of static storage duration variables is simply removed. This to reduce the time from reset to when main() is called. On such systems, *nothing* will execute the `static unsigned char myVar =5u;` code - your variable remains uninitialized and indeterminate even though you explicitly initialized it. You have to set it manually at "run-time", which is usually done from some init "constructor" code.
If you have `static uint8_t foo_count;` belonging to `foo.c`, then the `foo` module will have to provide a function `foo_init()` from where the code `foo_count = 5;` is executed.

Since the "minimized start-up" version is very common in embedded systems, it is usually considered dangerous to rely on default initialization of static storage duration variables, in case the code gets ported to such a system.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your start up code runs before main. with that said, when you declare the variable static, the variables scope is bound to the scope of that translation unit `(somefile.c)`, so yes you could overwrite it but that would be hard to do from other units (direct memory assignment) The golden rule for embedded systems is to avoid global variables but if you most, declare global variables as externs in a header file where it makes the most sense to put it.

Comment: It is the startup code that applies the initialisation.

Comment: Correct the runtime setup handles this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could replace this with a #define.

```
#define MY_VAR 5U
```

Comment: No you can't. That is a literal constant, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The start up code is what is responsible for applying the initialisation (where did you imagine that was done?), so yes it is safe and with respect to initialisation best practice.

Without initialisation a static or global should have a value of zero. It is not unheard of for the startup code in some embedded systems to deliberately omit zero initialisation in order to minimise start up time.  Normally that would not be the default startup code, and you would have to make a conscious decision to use it. It is unsafe and unfair to later maintainers who might be unaware is such non-standard behaviour.  It is also in most cases an unnecessary and *premature optimisation*. Nonetheless you might initialise all such variables, even if the unit is zero, to defend against such non standard startup (whilst also rendering it pointless, which it generally is).

What is *not* best practice is the use of a global in the first instance (https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/).  Though to be fair the `myVar` in question is not truly global in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly related with the original question, but I think it's worth mentioning:

Initialization of a global variable using another global variable from a different translation unit is not safe. For example:

In a.c

```
unsigned var_from_a = 5u;
```

In b.c

```
extern unsigned var_from_a;
unsigned var_from_b = var_from_a;
```

There is no guarantee that `var_from_b` becomes `5u`, because the initialization order of translation units is not defined. If you're unlucky, b.c is processed before a.c, and `var_from_b` may become `0` or some other garbage value, while a.c is processed later and `var_from_a` properly initialized to `5u`.

I'm not sure if it would change this behavior if `var_from_a` was defined as `const`.

Comment: `var_from_a` isn't an integer constant expression so it's not going to compile anyway.